# Model texture has issues when using normal map

Tags: normals, normal-map, shader-nodes

Whenever using normal map on a model, I get these odd fragments (the darker bits)

[image]

[image]

Node tree, its the most basic you can make it

[image]

Unplugging the normal map from the *Principled BSDF* fixes it but also takes away the normal map which I don't want.

[image]

[Blender file](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1wut4QAzviFw_XMd_1y6HU5RjBsv93ArP?usp=share_link)

EDIT: I want to share that this issue fixes itself in cycles but remains in eevee if that means anything

Comment: Looks like the strength might be topo high. Try 0.5 or so.

Comment: still shows but a little less. also gets rid of a lot of the details

Comment: Can you share the normal map or pack it into the blend file? It's not included.

Comment: the google drive folder i shared has a subfolder with the textures in case they diddnt pack

Comment: The normals are strong enough that they rotate the normal to be pointing away from the camera.  This breaks a number of calculations, but the most visually apparent are the calculations of Fresnel.  There are complicated solutions that will work only in specific situations, but Christopher Bennet is right that the best solution is to tune down the strength of the normal map, to eye, until the problems disappear.

Comment: they disappear completely at 0 but they also disappear in cycles and i dont plan on using eevee so it should be fine

Comment: Maybe it's a bug? In 2.93 (Eevee) there are no such artifacts but in 3.4. And yes, in Cycles everything looks fine.